# How to know the frequency of usage of a German word in speaking?

Tags: electronic-resources, german, word-frequency

Are there any apps or websites that show how frequently a German word is used in the spoken language and daily use ?

Comment: For which language(s)? And how would you use the frequency information?

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe  I want it for german language cause sometimes many words appear for an english translation, so I get confused to know which should I use in talking

Answer (score 4):

The type of resource you are looking for would be a **frequency list** or a **frequency dictionary** for German (in German: [Frequenzwörterbuch](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequenzw%C3%B6rterbuch)). This type of dictionaries is created on the basis of a [(text) corpus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_corpus). For the spoken language, it would be necessary to record people speaking German and then transcribe the dialogues, in order to get a text corpus that can be analysed. This is a time-consuming and expensive activity, so frequency dictionaries are typically not available for free.

The Institut für Deutsche Sprache in Mannheim, Germany, provides online access to its [**Datenbank für Gesprochenes Deutsch**](http://dgd.ids-mannheim.de/), but this gives you access only to a set of corpora, not to a frequency list.

On the website of the Institut für Deutsche Sprache, you can also find [DeReWo – Korpusbasierte Grund-/Wortformenlisten](http://www1.ids-mannheim.de/kl/projekte/methoden/derewo.html), but the lists available here appear to be based on written language.

The [Leipzig Corpora Collection / Deutscher Wortschatz](http://wortschatz.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/en) also offers lots of downloadable resources, but no frequency list for spoken German.

Instead of a website or an app, you may consider the following printed alternative: Tschirner, Erwin, Jones, Randall: [**A Frequency Dictionary of German: Core Vocabulary for Learners**](https://www.routledge.com/A-Frequency-Dictionary-of-German-Core-Vocabulary-for-Learners/Tschirner-Jones/p/book/9780415316330). Routledge, 2006. (190 pages; ISBN 9780415316330). 
The contains the 4,034 most frequently used words. According to the publisher: "Based on a 4.2 million-word corpus which is evenly divided between spoken, fiction and non-fiction texts." The dictionary is also available on **Google Play**: [A Frequency Dictionary of German: Core Vocabulary for Learners](https://play.google.com/store/books/details/A_Frequency_Dictionary_of_German_Core_Vocabulary_f?id=HwvICQAAQBAJ), but not cheap.